# Output results of if else statement to $subject and $body following a string output

Tags: email, powershell, smtp, if-statement

Hi im trying to output the results of the if/else statement  that will output the result from another text file into the subject line and the body of the email. I can get it to output to the powershell window but I cannot figure out how to get it to put it in the subject line and the body of the email. I am still very new to powershell so any help would be awesome.

thanks,

-Nick-

```
# Check if the migrater is running
$processToCheck = "calc"
$process = Get-Process $processToCheck
If (!($process))


# Check what step in the process its in 
{
$Service = get-content c:\AmicasToolService.properties | select-string           "#AmicasService.processes=ArchiveRetrievalTool"
If ($Service) {"is done migrating"}
Else {"is done retrieving"}

# Send Email With Results
$From = "Olorin Migration Status <olorinmigration@gmail.com>"
$To = "nwarner@rchsd.org"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Username = "email@gmail.com"
$Password = "password" 
$subject = "Tape"+" "+(select-string "000..."      c:\amicas2\config\ArchiveMigration.properties | select -Expand Matches | Select -Expand     Value) + ($step) 
$body = "Tape"+" "+(select-string "000..."   c:\amicas2\config\ArchiveMigration.properties | select -Expand Matches | Select -Expand Value) + " " + "has finished retrieval or migration to Centera. Please check the log in the   COA PACS folder for information on which step it is on in the process. \\naspfs01\Depts\ISD\COA\PACS\PACS_Library.xlsx"
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$smtp.Send($From, $To, $subject, $body);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
$msg = "$Service is done "
if ($Service) {
    $msg += "migrating"
}
else {
    $msg += "retrieving"
}

$subject = ... " $msg " ...
```

How I wished PowerShell had a ternary operator e.g.:

```
$msg += $service ? "migrating" : "retrieving"
```

If you agree, vote on it [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/53059/add-ternary-operator-to-script-language#details).